# Set overlay for a background page in javafx

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I need to set the background overlay to grey as shown in the image below when a popup is displayed. I have set the background page as the owner page to the popup. So other times when the popup is not displaying it has be normal. I was not able to achieve this. Please someone guide me. [image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit late... but you can try and use `ColorAdjust` in JavaFX:

```
         ColorAdjust dim = new ColorAdjust();
  
        dim.setBrightness(-0.4);
        stage.getScene().getRoot().setEffect(dim);
```

Set it on the `stage`  you desire and it should work.